# App en Flutter funciona bien en un dispositivo físico y simulador, pero al lanzar un release me da error de pod

Tags: flutter, ios, xcode, build

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Flutter y ya había construido y subido a connect el release en iOS, pero le agregue firebase_messaging y core, Funciona a la perfección en el simulador y en un dispositivo físico, pero al tratar de crear el Archive me manda un error, y al tratar de hacer un flutter build ios --release me arroja error.. en el release me arroja esto

CocoaPods' output:
↳
CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

```
    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization
not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:105:in `markdown_podfile'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:30:in `report'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization
not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:205:in `podfile'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:160:in `verify_podfile_exists!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Error running pod install

---

Y al tratar de hacer el Archive en Xcode me arroja este error

The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.

he intentado todo lo que he encontrado en intertet, desde borrar e instalar cocoa pods hasta borrar pods, update, install ... etc...

Alguna ayuda??

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo he podido solucionar con:

```
pod deintegrate    
pod update
pod install
```

igual si tienes un mac con procesador M1 la configuracion de pod es diferente, podrias revisar este post [Run CocoaPods on Apple Silicon (M1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/how-to-run-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1)

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por tomarse el tiempo, pero tampoco me resultaba el deintegrate...

Se resolvió como lo indico a continuación

Antes de construir el ejecutable escribí en la terminal:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

y solo con eso, o también puede funcionar el

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```